# A faster Search Algorithm in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowfilter

I'm trying to implement my own JTable RowFilter, since I'm using Java 1.4 (RowFilter doesn't seem to exist in this version). I still believe however that the algorithm that I'm using can be replaced by a much faster one. I have tried my algorithm on a dummy table that contains 30.000 records and 8 columns, and I'm getting the result in less than a second. But sometimes, there's this little delay that occurs while typing in the Search Criteria (Which is basically a JTextField with a DocumentListener). Here's the algorithm I'm using:

```
    public void searchList()
    {  

        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            Employee e=(Employee)list.get(i);

            Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(search.getText(),Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(e.getFname());
            if(matcher.find())
            {
                result.add(e);
                continue;   
            }
            matcher=pattern.matcher(e.getLname());
            if(matcher.find())
            {
                result.add(e);
                continue;   
            }
            matcher=pattern.matcher(e.getHeight());
            if(matcher.find())
            {
                result.add(e);
                continue;   
            }
            matcher=pattern.matcher(e.getOccupation());
            if(matcher.find())
            {
                result.add(e);
                continue;   
            }
            matcher=pattern.matcher(e.getSize());
            if(matcher.find())
            {
                result.add(e);
                continue;   
            }
            matcher=pattern.matcher(e.getSkills());
            if(matcher.find())
            {
                result.add(e);
                continue;   
            }
            matcher=pattern.matcher(e.getSsn());
            if(matcher.find())
            {
                result.add(e);
                continue;   
            }
            matcher=pattern.matcher(e.getStrength());
            if(matcher.find())
            {
                result.add(e);

            }
        }
        model.fireTableDataChanged();
        table.updateUI();
    }
    }
```

The main datastructure that I'm using to bind data to my TableModel is an ArrayList that holds objects of a class called "Employee". Another ArrayList called result, contains all the "Employee" objects that matched the search criteria. Bear in mind that the filtering is happening on all 8 columns. The only optimization that I think I did is adding the "Employee" object on the first column match, instead of having to go through the rest of the columns.

Any suggestions regarding this matter? Thanks a lot for the help =)

Comment: unrelated to your problem, nevertheless important: never-ever call updateUI in application code! It's there for the (near-) exclusive use of the pluggable LAF mechanism. If you feel compelled to do it (because it solves some seemingly untractable update problems) something is wrong with code and needs immediate attention

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you seem to be searching for the exact same value in all fields, I would just concatenate them and do the matching once.

Also, I don't think there is any good reason why you would compile the pattern in every iteration.

Comment: Concatenating has to be handled with care. Assuming, we have column values "abc" and "def" and look for "cde" - with concatenation it will be a false positive. -> So don't forget to insert separators if going for concat (like "abc"+"@@"+"def" instead of "abc"+"def")

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. And Fredrik, I have just realized that I have put the Patter.compile inside my FOR loop by mistake. Thanks for the alert though ;)

Comment: Just to update you guys on my question, I have finally done the following:

1- Concatenated all the fields together with a separator between them ( the "!")
2- Downloaded the SearchString library from this link 
http://johannburkard.de/software/stringsearch/

3- Converted the concatenated string and the search criteria patten to lowerCase.

4- Used the Boyer Moore, Raita algorithm by doing the following:

<code>
BoyerMooreHorspoolRaita searchAl=new BoyerMooreHorspoolRaita();
</code>
Then I did this:
<code>
int j=searchAl.searchString(match, search.getText());
if(j!=-1)
result.add(e);
</code>

Answer (score 0):

Just to update you guys on my question, I have finally done the following: 1- Concatenated all the fields together with a separator between them ( the "!") 2- Downloaded the SearchString library from this link johannburkard.de/software/stringsearch 3- Converted the concatenated string and the search criteria patten to lowerCase. 4- Used the Boyer Moore, Raita algorithm by doing the following:  `BoyerMooreHorspoolRaita searchAl=new BoyerMooreHorspoolRaita();`

Then I did this:  
`int j=searchAl.searchString(match, search.getText()); if(j!=-1) result.add(e);`

I tried comparing the first method that I used with this one, in a table that contained 100000 records, and the results were as follows:

Pattern Matching:
**FIRST RUN:**
1 Character long pattern: Operation took 3.328 seconds to complete
2 Characters long pattern: Operation took 14.14 seconds to complete
3 Characters long pattern: Operation took 11.328 seconds to complete
4 Characters long pattern: Operation took 8.437 seconds to complete
5 Characters long pattern: Operation took 8.344 seconds to complete
6 Characters long pattern: Operation took 8.078 seconds to complete

**SECOND RUN:**
1 Character long pattern: Operation took 3.281 seconds to complete
2 Characters long pattern: Operation took 14.14 seconds to complete
3 Characters long pattern: Operation took 11.344 seconds to complete
4 Characters long pattern: Operation took 8.375 seconds to complete
5 Characters long pattern: Operation took 8.469 seconds to complete
6 Characters long pattern: Operation took 8.266 seconds to complete

**Boyer Moore RAITA:**
FIRST RUN:
1 Character long pattern: Operation took 11.688 seconds to complete
2 Characters long pattern: Operation took 10.594 seconds to complete
3 Characters long pattern: Operation took 7.563 seconds to complete
4 Characters long pattern: Operation took 4.328 seconds to complete
5 Characters long pattern: Operation took 4.5 seconds to complete
6 Characters long pattern: Operation took 4.969 seconds to complete

**SECOND RUN:**
1 Character long pattern: Operation took 8.172 seconds to complete
2 Characters long pattern: Operation took 8.312 seconds to complete
3 Characters long pattern: Operation took 5.484 seconds to complete
4 Characters long pattern: Operation took 3.922 seconds to complete
5 Characters long pattern: Operation took 3.922 seconds to complete
6 Characters long pattern: Operation took 4.047 seconds to complete

Notice that Pattern Filtering (The first method ) is faster when it comes to a single character matching. But the Boyer Moore Horspool Raita just SHINES as the length of the pattern increases.

I hope this will help someone somehow. 
Cheers.